# Where do I find the contents of $this->getAbsoluteFooter() Magento

Tags: magento

I'm struggling to find what this calls '$this->getAbsoluteFooter()' or where it's contents are.
Is it a template file?

The reason I ask is because my site was hacked with a js injection in the footer. Disabling $this->getAbsoluteFooter() removed the injection so I'm anxious to find the source.

I've Googled it and the only thing I can find is someone asking the same question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've been hacked which means this could be anywhere, so keep that in mind when this doesn't work for you.

The `getAbsoluteFooter` method is normally defined in the following file.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php
public function getAbsoluteFooter()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('design/footer/absolute_footer');
}
```

In a normal system, the `getStoreConfig` method will return the value stored in `core_config_data` for the passed in path (`design/footer/absolute_footer`).

Of course, since you're hacked, the actual class file `$this` refers to in your template could be anywhere on the server (depending on the severity of your hack).  Give the following a try to find the real file on your specific system

```
//$this->getAbsoluteFooter();
$r = new ReflectionClass($this);
var_dump($r->getFilename());
```

That should reveal the actual filename, which may be `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php`, or may be something else.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that. You are correct it turned out to be app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php which pointed me in the direction of design/footer, which was in core_config_data. The bad code was in there. I could have simply looked in System > Configuration > Design first and I would have seen it. Ultimately I fixed it and it looks like bad password security. Client keeps creating new users with simple passwords. Not any more ;-)

Comment: @Grry Glad it wasn't something more serious.  Don't forget to upvote and mark this as the accepted answer to increase your Stack Overflow reputation.

Comment: This has turned out to be a new Magento Hack that has started in the last few days. 8000+ sites affected according to Zdnet http://www.zdnet.com/article/thousands-of-e-commerce-magento-websites-struck-with-guruncsite-malware/ No information yet on how they are getting in.

Comment: @Gerry are you up to date on all your security patches?  There have been a number of them this year to fix fault in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that a code was injected in the database on the core_config_data table with path 'design/footer/absolute_footer';
More on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42529/57576
Ty